# In C++ why is it when I reassign a reference variable to a different reference variable it creates a copy of that variable instead?

Tags: c++, reference

```
struct configfs
{
    int & foo;
    configfs(int & foo_) : foo(foo_) {}

    void set_foo(int & foo_)
    {
        foo = foo_;
    }

};

int main() { 
    int a = 1;
    configfs conf(a);
    a = 3;
    std::cout << conf.foo; // 3
    std::cout << a;      // 3

    int b = 2;
    conf.set_foo(b);
    b = 9;
    std::cout << conf.foo; // 2
    std::cout << b;        // 9

    return 0;
}
```

When I initialize `configfs` with `int a` and then alter a in the main function it also alters `configfs.foo` . But when I reassign `configfs.foo` to a new reference and alter that reference in the main function, the behavior is different. Why? Is there a way so that when I run `conf.set_foo(b)` and then alter b in the main scope, it also alters `conf.foo` as well?

Comment: Because you cannot reassign a reference: it will copy the value. With a pointer, it would be possible.

Comment: "When I reassign `configfs.foo` to a new reference" references are not reassignable. You're just assigning the value currently in `b` to `foo`, aka `a`, but you're not making it so that `foo` is now a reference to `b` instead of a reference to `a`.

Comment: If you want something that acts like a reference but _is_ reassignable, consider [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Comment: Are you coming to C++ with experience in another language like C# or Java?  References in C++ are not like references in C# or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrote:

```
conf.set_foo(b);
```

The following things happen:

1. Member function `set_foo` is called on the object `conf`.
2. Moreover, the reference parameter named `foo_` is bound the the argument named `b`. That is, `b` is passed by reference.
3. Next, the statement `foo = foo_;` is encountered. This is an **assigment** statement and not an **initialization**. What this does is that it **assigns** the value referred to by the parameter `foo_` to the object referred to by the data member `foo`(which is nothing but `a` here). You can [confirm this](https://onlinegdb.com/zukQtWLksz) by adding `std::cout<<a;` after the call to `set_foo` as shown below:

```
int b = 2;
conf.set_foo(b);
std::cout<<a<<std::endl;  //prints 2
```

This is because operations on a reference are actually operations on the object to which the reference is bound.  This means that when we **assign** to a reference, we are assigning to the object to which the reference
is bound. When we **fetch** the value of a reference, we are really fetching the value of the object to which the reference is bound.

---

**Note:** 
 Once **initialized**, a reference remains bound to its initial object. There is no way to rebind a reference to refer to a different
object.

Answer (score 1):

Refercences can only be "assigned" during initialization. They cannot be "retargeted" the way like pointers. After the initialization the memory the reference refers to remains fixed and any assignment using `=` results in the invokation of the assignment operator to the memory the reference refers to.  That's the way it's specified in the C++ standard.

You could rewrite the example using a custom type with assignment operators printing the information about calls:

```
template<class T>
struct configfs
{
    T& foo;
    configfs(T& foo_) : foo(foo_) {}

    void set_foo(T& foo_)
    {
        foo = foo_; // this uses the assignment operator assigning to the variable foo is an alias for
    }

};

// Type wrapping the int and printing out the operations applied
struct TestWrapper
{
    TestWrapper(int value)
        : value(value)
    {
        std::cout << "TestWrapper::TestWrapper(" << value << ")\n";
    }

    TestWrapper(TestWrapper const& other)
        : value(other.value)
    {
        std::cout << "TestWrapper::TestWrapper(TestWrapper{" << other.value << "})\n";
    }

    TestWrapper& operator=(TestWrapper const& other)
    {
        std::cout << "TestWrapper::operator=(TestWrapper{" << other.value << "})\n";
        value = other.value;
        return *this;
    }

    int value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, TestWrapper const& val)
{
    s << val.value;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    TestWrapper a = 1;
    configfs<TestWrapper> conf(a);
    a = 3;
    std::cout << conf.foo << '\n'; // 3
    std::cout << a << '\n';      // 3

    TestWrapper b = 2;
    conf.set_foo(b); // TestWrapper::operator=(TestWrapper{2})
    b = 9;
    std::cout << conf.foo << '\n'; // 2
    std::cout << b << '\n';        // 9

    return 0;
}
```